# how do I use the node Builder from Scriptacolus to insert html

Tags: javascript, dom, scriptaculous

for example this code

```
var html = "<p>This text is <a href=#> good</a></p>";
var newNode = Builder.node('div',{className: 'test'},[html]);
$('placeholder').update(newNode);
```

casues the p and a tags to be shown,  how do I prevent them from being escaped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last parameter to Builder.node is "Array, List of other nodes to be appended as children" according to the [Wiki](http://github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/wikis/builder). So when you pass it a string it is treated like text.

You could use:

```
var a = Builder.node('div').update("<a href='#'>foo</a>")
```

Where the link is text or:

```
var a = Builder.node('div', {'class':'cool'}, 
         [Builder.node('div', {'class': 'another_div'})]
        );
```

And you could use just Prototypes [new Element()](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element) (Available as of version 1.6).

```
var a = new Element('div').insert(
          new Element('div', {'class': 'inner_div'}).update("Text in the inner div")
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution: http://sviudes.blogspot.com/2009/08/como-usar-etiquetas-html-con.html